# Python Mysqldb Returns Question Marks

Tags: python, mysql

I am using the following code in python and it seems to be returning the "Name" as question marks since the name is in russian. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root",passwd="*****")
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("USE WebCorpusStatus;")
cur.execute("SELECT Name, Source, Date(dateScraped) FROM russian WHERE status = 1;")
for row in cur:    
    print row
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQLdb.connect takes a use_unicode parameter, which may solve the problem. If not, you may also need to set charset to whatever your table uses:

```
MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root",passwd="*****", use_unicode=True, charset='xxxxx')
```

http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html

Comment: I tried this but it still does not work. I am trying to use charset='koi8r' for russian, but it gives me the following error: LookupError: unknown encoding: koi8r

Comment: @compsci101: Try `koi8_r`.

Comment: unutbu - error: _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2019, "Can't initialize character set koi8_r (path: /usr/share/mysql/charsets/)")

Comment: It might be `koi8-r`? Does `locale -m`show that you have KOI8-R installed?

Comment: it is still not working. locale -m does show that I have KOI8-R installed but it gives the same error as above.