# How to convert question marks instead text to cyrillic?

Tags: python, mysql, character-encoding

While printing Cyrillic text from MySQL in my python3 program I get question marks instead of text.

The text I see in the MySQL table is `Рожден ден`.

The text I see in the python3 program is `?????? ???`.

Type of row is class str.

For this list, I am using wxpython, wx module.

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', database='Tasks', password='password', user='user')
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        cursor.execute('SELECT occasion,date,event FROM Important_Days')  
        records = cursor.fetchall()

        for row in records:
                pos = self.list1.InsertStringItem(0, row[0])
                self.list1.SetStringItem(pos, 1, str(row[1]))
                self.list1.SetStringItem(pos, 2, row[2])

        conn.close()
```

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15907509/python-cyrillic-decode) uses a different driver (MySQLdb) but the highest-scoring answer shows a way to configure MySQL to handle unicode.  The accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17901459/python-mysqldb-returns-question-marks), again for MySQLdb, shows the parameters to set on the `connect` call.  It's worth googling how to best configure MySQL to handle unicode.  Take a backup before changing any database settings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python cyrillic decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15907509/python-cyrillic-decode)

Comment: There are probably better duplicates but they depend on how exactly you configured things on the MySQL end. A general possible duplicate is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46061496/python3-encoding-for-mysql-database

Answer (score 0):

The question marks were created during the `INSERTs`, there is no way to get the Cyrillic out of them.

See "question mark" in [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

See this for notes on Python:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python